# TreeSet is adding duplicate values to the Set

Tags: java, collections

I am solving a problem. I have to create a TreeSet of custom Employee objects where data should be sorted by salary but employee Id needs to be unique. I understand that equals() and hashCode() method doesn't work for TreeSet and we need to write our object are equal or not logic inside the compareTo() method. I am checking if both employee Id are equal then return 0, means object should not be added.

But the output is not coming as desired as employees with same employee Id are also getting added. I tried to debug this but I am not getting the right answer.

This is the code.

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>{
    int empId;
    String empName;
    double salary;
    
    public Employee() {
        super();
    }

    public Employee(int empId, String empName, double salary) {
        super();
        this.empId = empId;
        this.empName = empName;
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return empId;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(this == o) return true;
        if(o == null || this.getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        
        Employee e = (Employee) o;
        return (this.empId == e.empId);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return empId + " " + empName + " " + salary;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Employee e) {
        if(empId == e.empId) 
            return 0;
        
        if(this.salary < e.salary) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

The main method of program

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        TreeSet<Employee> eSet = new TreeSet<>();
        
        eSet.add(new Employee(1, "john", 20000));
        eSet.add(new Employee(2, "jim", 10000));
        eSet.add(new Employee(9, "mike", 50000));
        eSet.add(new Employee(3, "jack", 30000));
        eSet.add(new Employee(3, "david", 40000));
        eSet.add(new Employee(9, "liam", 80000));
        eSet.add(new Employee(9, "brad", 89000));
        eSet.add(new Employee(3, "jason", 85000));
        eSet.add(new Employee(2, "ted", 35000));
        
        for(Employee e: eSet) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

The output of above program comes out as

```
2 jim 10000.0
1 john 20000.0
3 jack 30000.0
2 ted 35000.0
9 mike 50000.0
3 jason 85000.0
```

Here as you can see employees with same employee Id are being added to the TreeSet which should not happen. If I am using a HashSet the problem is resolved, but I have to implement it using TreeSet to get the sorted behaviour.

Can someone please guide me where am I going wrong?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko that is not the problem here. The implementation of the `Comparable` interface is consistent with the `equals()`-implementation. The problem is the ordering, since `ted` (who is ordered to a different position as `jim`) is not "*found*" when adding (I think due to binary search).

Comment: @Turing85 Hm, I see now, you are right implementations are consistent.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko problem is that the `Comparable`-implementation violates transitivity.

Comment: @Turing85 But how exactly? How does the `compareTo` implementation ever get past the `if(empId == e.empId)` test? Duplicates should always be rejected by the `TreeSet` based on this first `if` test, and never get to the part comparing `salary`. Obviously I am wrong in some way, as I ran the Question's code — I too found the duplicates "2 ted" and "3 jason".

Comment: @BasilBourque set a break point. The problem is that `jim` and `ted` are never compared.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The implementation of `Comparable` violates the [contract of `Comparable::compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html), in particular this part:

> Finally, the implementor must ensure that `x.compareTo(y)==0` implies that `signum(x.compareTo(z)) == signum(y.compareTo(z))`, for all `z`.

We can demonstrate this violation with the following code:

```
final Employee jim = new Employee(2, "jim", 10_000);
final Employee ted = new Employee(2, "ted", 35_000);
final Employee john = new Employee(9, "john", 20_000);

System.out.println("jim compare to ted: " + jim.compareTo(ted));
System.out.println("john compare to jim: " + john.compareTo(jim));
System.out.println("john compare to ted: " + john.compareTo(ted));
```

leading to the following output:

```
jim compare to ted: 0
john compare to jim: 1
john compare to ted: -1
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/RulANI)

We can fix this issue by dropping the salary from the `compareTo`-method and only order by `empId`:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Employee e) {
  return Integer.compare(empId, e.empId);
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/N2IHag)

Comment: So due to broken transitivity "jim" and "ted" and up in the different branches of the tree.

Comment: It is not the transitivity (my initial comment wrt. transitivity is wrong), it is the condition I quoted (I think it does not have a mathematical name). But yes, the gist of it is that in the original code, `jim` and `ted` a renever directly compared.

Comment: So the original logic went wrong when the `compareTo` tried to add a secondary sort, did so incorrectly, and violated the constancy with the `equals` method. Is the generalized lesson to learn here that natural ordering cannot have a secondary level of sorting?

Comment: @BasilBourque they can (I think), but they must truly be secondary, i.e. the primary attribute(s) must be checked first.

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks for the solution. Yes if I am comparing only empId then there is no issue of duplicates. But I did not understand that they should be truly secondary attributes part. Can we compare or have two sorting logics inside a compareTo method? If I want to have employees set info sorted on basis of salary, how can I do this inside compareTo() or there is no way for this?

Comment: You need to satisfy the contract of `Comparable::compareTo`. That's all.

Comment: @BasilBourque The "consistent with equals" issue isn't relevant here. The main issue, as correctly described by this answer, are the fundamentals of the contract need to be satisfied.

Comment: @scarletspeedster The criteria that determine the uniqueness of objects in the set must be the *same* as the criteria that determine the ordering of the objects. It sounds like you want uniqueness based on employee ID but ordering based on salary. You can't write a single, correct `compareTo` method that does both. If that's what you want, you need to use something other than or in addition to a `TreeSet`.

Comment: ... or first add all values, then sort (by, for example, transferring all elements in another `TreeSet` with a custom/different `Comparator`). It really boils down to the fact that we have two concerns: uniqueness and ordering.

Comment: While considering all elements with the same `empId` to be equal, is valid according to the Collection API’s contract, I still see a semantic problem with having obviously different employees (different name, different salary) with the same id. In real life, there should be only a single employee with a particular id in the first place. Then, using a comparator sorting by salary first and by empId as secondary criteria would do the right thing. In contrast, killing poor Ted because someone messed up the IDs and gave him the same as Jim’s, is not a reasonable behavior at all.